# How to find the SE tour?

Tags: discussion

This isn't a home improvement question, rather a SE question:

**How do I find "the tour" for SE.**

I may be just very dense, but I can't find it. I've recommended it at times for newbies, but would like to include a link to make it easier for them. Somehow I just can't find it.

Perhaps the programmers at SE could make it more accessible and obvious.

Comment: You can also type `[tour]` in a comment and it will hotlink it, as in "Take the [tour]".  Also works for [edit].

Comment: Thank you very much. I felt dumb about not finding that again.

Answer (score 3):

In the upper right hand corner of the page, to the right of the search box,  are several icons.

If you click on the round one with a question mark in it you will get  a drop down menu and "[tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)" is the top option in the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Scroll to the bottom of the page of questions. It's at the top of the list on the left hand side under HOME IMPROVEMENT.
Edit: On a phone it is also at the bottom of the page. When you scroll down there is a black menu bar at the bottom with the options: meta, chat, tour, help, etc.

Comment: I know it's there on a computer, and I never visit the site on a phone. Is it the same on a phone? I know some things are often quite different.